# How to copy a formula over to other columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Table that I created through a previous Macro.

With the help from another question, I was able to find “All Other” in Column B, and insert a formula in the adjacent column.

**PrintScreen:**
[image]

Now I would like to copy the formula from the Unknown Active Cell, and paste it into the adjacent Columns: D, E, G, H, I, J, and L `Offset – 0 Rows`.

I currently have:

```
Sub AllOther()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aOther As Range
Dim DataLastRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet

DataLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Set aOther = ws.Range("B:B").Find("All Other", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not aOther is Nothing Then
        aOther.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 1).Address & ":" & ws.Cells(DataLastRow,3).Address & ")"
    Else
        MsgBox """All Other"" not found in column."
    End If

'Copy/Paste into other Columns
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Q1/** What is the "*Unknown Active Cell"* you are referring to?

**Q2/** What do you you want to sum in the formula
*=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 1).Address & ":" & ws.Cells(DataLastRow,3).Address & ")"* ?

The beginning of the range *aOther.Offset(3, 1).Address* is 3 rows **below** aOther and the end of the range is anywhere.

Anyway it will be easier if in the formula you do not mix an offset of *aOther* with an offset of *ws*.

**3/** doing so would enable you to loop as in the following code

```
Sub AllOther()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aOther As Long
    Dim aOtherRow As Integer ' row

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array(3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11) ' columns to sum

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set aOther = ws.Range("B:B").Find("All Other", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row

    If Not aOther Is Nothing Then
        aOtherRow = aOther.Row
        For Each i In arr
            ws.Cells(aOtherRow, i).Formula = "=SUM(" & ws.Cells(FirstRow, i).Address & ":" & ws.Cells(LastRow, i) & ")"
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox """All Other"" not found in column."
    End If
End Sub
```

In which *FirstRow* and *LastRow* depend of the answer to Q2

------------------- Edit after  Cari Day answers ------------------------

```
Sub AllOther()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aOther As Range

    Dim aOtherRow As Long
    Dim DataFirstRow As Long
    Dim DataLastRow As Long
    Dim col as integer

    Dim ColumnsArray As Variant
    ColumnsArray = Array(3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11) ' columns to sum


    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set aOther = ws.Range("B:B").Find("All Other", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not aOther Is Nothing Then
        aOtherRow = aOther.Row
        DataFirstRow = aOtherRow + 1
        DataLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each col In ColumnsArray
            ws.Cells(aOtherRow, col).Formula = "=SUM(" & ws.Cells(DataFirstRow, col).Address & ":" & ws.Cells(DataLastRow, col).Address & ")"
        Next col
    Else
        MsgBox """All Other"" not found in column."
    End If
End sub
```

Comment: Q1 – The “Unknown Active Cell” comes from the first portion of the macro which `Finds “All Other”` in Column B.

Comment: Q2 - Once “All Other” is found, the Formula is placed in `Column C - aOther.Offset(0, 1)`.    The Formula Sums the data starting 3 Rows below the Formula Cell: ` aOther.Offset(3, 1).Address`  and references Column A for the End Data: ` DataLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Basically, I would like Sum all the Data 3 rows down from the Cell, and Reference Column A for the End Data.  But I won’t know the Cell to place the formula in without referencing the “All Other”.  Should is use the same formula but Instead keep adding to the Column offset - `aOther.Offset(0, 1)`?